# Use a c# assembly's namespace in a f# application?

Tags: f#

There is a c# assembly with a public static class `Something`.
It has a public static method `DoSomething(string source, string dest, string file, string arch)`

I do not know f# and there is no one in the shop who knows it anymore, but I need to replace an API that one f# project uses with what's in the c# assembly.

I wanted to use that method in another solution's f# project, and added a reference to the first assembly's \bin\Debug\Something.exe (yes, it doubles as a command line EXE).

Then I added `open Something` to the f# unit where it is needed. Once the .NET versions were in sync, the assembly seemed to have loaded.

Now that I code this snippet:

```
let src = "C:\"
let dst = "D:\"
let file = "readme.txt"
let arch = "E:\"
Something.DoSomething src dst file arch
```

it does not build due to this error:

```
Error   2
The member or object constructor 'DoSomething' takes 4 argument(s) but is here given 1.
The required signature is 'Something.DoSomething(source: string, dest: string, ?file: string, ?archive: string) : bool'.
```

Am I really passing just 1 argument erroneously believing I am passing all 4?

Comment: Being defined in C#, `DoSomething` is a method, not a function; method parameters always need to be tupled, that is parenthesized and separated by commas, even when called from F#.

Comment: Sorry, this is French for me.

Comment: The error says `The required signature is 'Something.DoSomething(source: string, dest: string, ?file: string, ?archive: string) : bool'.` That means your call needs to be `Something.DoSomething(src, dst, file, arc)`, just like it would be in C#.

Comment: That simple?! Thx*10^6

Answer (score 5):

You need to treat it as a tupled method:

```
Something.DoSomething (src, dst, file, arch)
```

This should allow it to compile and call the method correctly.